# Variables in content_tag blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been looking for this and can't seem to find a solution:

I have a content_tag block with a lot of logic in a helper (probably not great, but it is what it is). There's a variable in there that needs to increment. However, the code like this

num = num + 1

Actually ends up outputting num + 1 instead of incrementing it. Is there a way to temporarily evaluate that expression instead of outputting it in the buffer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content_tag` helper will return the result of the block, which will be the last line inside the block.  I am guessing that you're incrementing code is the last line - try moving the output string after this line.